# How to run cmd before generate cache in vs2019 cmake project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to migrate my C++ project build environment from linux to windows, both using cmake. But I meet an error when vs generate cache. It can't find the source files which should be generated by a sub-project.

On Linux, the sub-project will run a python script to generate files which provide to other sub-project as source files. I add "execute_process" cmd in CMakeList.txt to entrue all the files will be generated when we type "cmake ..".

```
execute_process(
COMMAND python3 ${GENSRC_DIR}/gensrc.py -${GEN_FLAG} --oh_dir=${OH_DIR}
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${QLA_DIR}/gensrc)
```

After migrate to vs2019, the first step is generating cmake cache. It doesn't call "execute_process", so there is an error: "Cannot find source file: XXXXXX".
Any suggestions?

Comment: low-hanging-fruit question - do you have python installed on MS-Windows ?

Comment: `execute_process` should work. There is no step "generating cmake cache". Please, show the **exact error message** you faced with. (Error message should include the name of file which cannot be found and the line in `CMakeLists.txt` which causes the error.)

Comment: @RichardCritten, Ah~~~~~~  I'm a fool. thank you very much.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Richard is right, I have python install, not python3